# Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.Int32]' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, lambda

I am trying to populate a data list box to text box on list box's click event but I found this error

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.Int32]' to type 'System.IConvertible'

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StudenRecordDataContext std = new StudentRecordDataContext();
    int selectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.SelectedValue);
    StudentRecord sr = std.StudentRecords.Single(s =>s.ID==selectedValue);
    txtId.Text = sr.ID.ToString();
    txtName.Text = sr.Name;
    txtPassword.Text = sr.Password;
    txtCnic.Text = sr.CNIC;
    txtEmail.Text = sr.Email;
}
```

I think the error is on line `StudentRecord sr = std.StudentRecords.Single(s =>s.ID==selectedValue);`

Where does that error come from and what do I need to change to fix that error?

Comment: didn't work bro and ID is of type int

Comment: So where do you get this error?

Comment: from third line when i use lambda exp

Comment: StudentRecord sr = std.StudentRecords.Single(s =>s.ID==selectedValue);

Comment: Have you got the error on exactly this code or it is a simplified version of your code?

Comment: yeah exactly on this line of code

Comment: Try to Clean then Build your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to say so but you provided us with the wrong diagnosis of the line your program fails.

The culprit is this line:

```
int selectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.SelectedValue);
```

I expect you have earlier populated that `listbox1` with a collection from `StudentRecords` coming from an instance of your `StudentRecordDataContext`.

If you select a value from the listbox the [`SelectedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) holds the object you added to the items collection (or indirectly by setting the `DataSource` property).

To fix your code you could first make sure the object becomes a `StudentRecord` again. That is not that easy because you created an anonymous type, I expect something like:

```
 listbox1.DataSource = new StudentRecordDataContext()
    .StudentRecords
    .Select(sr => new { Name = sr.Name, ID = sr.ID });
```

When you try to retrieve the SelectedValue you get that anonymous type, not something that is strongly typed.

Instead of adding an anonymous type, create a new class that has the properties for the Name and the Id:

```
class StudentRecordItem 
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public int ID {get; set;}
}
```

When you populate the Datasource create StudentRecordItem classes for each record and add those to the datasource.

```
 listbox1.DataSource = new StudentRecordDataContext()
    .StudentRecords
    .Select(sr => new StudentRecordItem { Name = sr.Name, ID = sr.ID });
```

The your code can become something like this:

```
StudentRecordItem selectedStudent =  listBox1.SelectedValue as StudentRecordItem;
if (selectedStudent == null) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("No student record");
    return;
}

int selectedValue = selectedStudent.ID;
```

You don't need the `Convert.ToInt32` because I assume `ID` is already an int.

Remember that the [debugger in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kya29xtx.aspx) shows the actual types and values of all your properties and variables. When a type conversion fails you can inspect there what the actual type is you're working with.